# Assign values in returned dictionary to unique variables

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def foodColors():
    """Example function to return dictionary of food colors."""
    appleColor = getAppleCol() # long magic function
    return {'apple':appleColor, 'carrot':'orange', 'grape':'green'}
```

If a function returns a dictionary as shown above, and the function call takes longer than wanted, what is the best way to assign the returned values to unique variables? For example, my application does not care about carrot color and does not know how `foodColors()` is implemented.

I'm currently doing the obvious:

```
colorDict = foodColors()
apple = colorDict['apple']
grape = colorDict['grape']
```

This method is fine, but I was hoping someone might have a better solution or be able to show a unique way to unpack the return values inline such as:

```
apple, grape = foodColors()['apple','grape'] # made up syntax
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `operator.itemgetter`:

```
apple, grape = itemgetter('apple', 'grape')(foodColors())
```

Of course, you can re-use the itemgetter function if you want:

```
getter = itemgetter('apple', 'grape')
apple, grape = getter(foodColors())
apple2, grape2 = getter(foodColors())
```

Comment: Itemgetter only accepts multiple arguments in version 2.5+ (i tagged this question 2.7 and this solution worked well there. trying it in my 2.4 environment did not work -- my fault though).

Comment: @Caprooja -- Fair enough.  python2.4 is a little before my time :)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly (depending on how you use your dict), [`namedtuples`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields) could also be a solution:

```
from collections import namedtuple

color_dict = {'apple': 'red',
              'carrot':'orange',
              'grape':'green'}

# Create a namedtuple class
ColorMap = namedtuple('ColorMap', ['apple', 'carrot', 'grape'])

# Create an instance of ColorMap by using the unpacked dictionary
# as keyword arguments to the constructor
color_map = ColorMap(**color_dict)

# Unpack the namedtuple like you would a regular one
apple, carrot, grape = color_map
```

**Advantages**

- `namedtuples` are *extremely* lightweight
- Nice dotted attribute access (`obj.attr`)

**Disadvantages**

- To use the unpacking like I showed on the last line, you will always need to unpack **all** values, if you need them or not. Maybe that works for your or someone else's use case, maybe it doesn't.

Of course, if `namedtuples` fit the bill, you can skip the intermediate dictionary entirely.

---

**Background**

There's something very similar to your toy syntax

```
apple, grape = foodColors()['apple','grape'] # made up syntax
```

that **almost** works:

```
apple, grape = foodColors().values()
```

(Getting only the list of values from the dict and unpacking it like a regular tuple).
The problem with this is that dictionaries aren't ordered (their key/value pairs are in an arbitrary order. Not random (not at all), but arbitrary, and the order will change [as the dictionary's size changes](http://pyvideo.org/video/276/the-mighty-dictionary-55)).

The fields of named tuples however are ordered (like regular tuples have an order, in a `namedtuple` they're just *named* fields). So in a way, you get some of the benefits of dictionary as well as lightweight ordered structures like tuples. That's why they can be unpacked to an ordered sequence.

However, if you do that, you rely on the exact order of the fields in the tuple, and therefore give up one of the great advantages they offer. For more on `namedtuples` and why they're awesome, see [PyCon 2011: Fun with Python's Newer Tools](http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011/pycon-2011-fun-with-python-s-newer-tools-4901215) by Raymond Hettinger.